# is it possible to use a vpn in two separate virtualboxes simultaneously on windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, openvpn

specifically
I'm running Ubuntu with this...
https://github.com/philipperemy/expressvpn-python

https://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldnt be any reason you couldnt.  A VPN wouldnt know if was running in a virtual machine, nor should it make a difference.  It simply creates an encrypted tunnel between two points.

I dont know anything about the software you are linking, so I dont know what its limitations are.  The only real issue I could think of would be from the endpoint of the VPN.  Assuming you are using a home computer and the endpoint only allows one connection per IP, both connections would be coming from your single public IP and it wouldnt allow it.  However, one can think of an infinite hypothetical issues if given enough time...